# pyarrow append and read row/columns for time series data

Tags: io, time-series, parquet, pyarrow

I am looking to use pyarrow to do memory mapped reads both for row and columns, for time series data with multiple columns. I Don't really care about writing historical data at a slower speed. My main aim is the fastest read speed (for single row, single columns, multiple row columns), and there after the fastest possible append speed (with rows appended periodically). Here is the code that generates data I am looking to test on. This is a multiindex dataframe with columns as fields (open, high, low ...) and the index is a two level multiindex with datetime and symbols as the two levels. Comments on this particular architecture are also welcome.

```
import time
import psutil, os

KB = 1<<10
MB = 1024 * KB
GB = 1024 * MB

idx = pd.date_range('20150101', '20210613', freq='T')
df = {}
for j in range(10):
    df[j] = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(len(idx), 6), index=idx, columns=[i for i in 'ohlcvi'])
df = pd.concat(df, axis=1)
df = df.stack(level=0)
df.index.names=['datetime', 'sym']
df.columns.name = 'field'
print(df.memory_usage().sum()/GB)
```

Now I am looking for the most efficient code to do the following:

1. Write this data in a memory mapped format on disk so that It can be used to read rows/columns or some random access.
2. Append another row to this dataset at the end.
3. query the last 5 rows.
4. query a few random columns for a given set of continuous rows.
5. query non continuous rows and columns.

If the task masters are looking for how I did it before they allow anybody to answer this question, please respond and I will roll out all the preliminary code I wrote to accomplish this. I am not doing it here as It will probably dirty up the space without much info. I did not get speeds promised on blogs on pyarrow and I am sure I am doing it wrong, thus this request for guidance.

Comment: A few things: can you link the blog post(s) you are referencing and add the speeds you expect and the speeds you get? Are you writing Feather/IPC or Parquet? What code have you written for this? (Note that these are columnar formats, so random-access rows may not be the best suited use case.)